# How to use cabal install for regular expression package installation?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

Am working through Real World Haskell and am trying to install regex-posix-0.95.2 from an untar[ed] package by simplying running

```
cabal install
```

I then see:

```
Text/Regex/Posix/Wrap.hsc:141:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike’
    There are files missing in the ‘regex-base-0.93.2’ package,
    try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
    |
141 | import Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike(RegexOptions(..),RegexMaker(..),RegexContext(..),MatchArray)
```

Despite the fact that I can load this in ghci with

```
Prelude> :module Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike
Prelude Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike>
```

```
Prelude> import Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike(RegexOptions(..),RegexMaker(..),RegexContext(..),MatchArray)
Prelude Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike>
```

and see it in the module-system.

```
[warrick@warrick-pc regex-posix-0.95.2]$ ghc-pkg find-module Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike
/usr/lib/ghc-8.6.2/package.conf.d
    regex-base-0.93.2
```

Why is this failing?

What are some more general tips and tricks when trying to debug cabal failures you'd recommend (as this is one instance of many issues I'm consistently having with Cabal)?

Comment: Does the module contains all the required "ingredients"? WHat if you write `import Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike(RegexOptions(..),RegexMaker(..),RegexContext(..),MatchArray)` on the shell (in case the package is too old/young, that can fail).

Comment: Yes,  that command also works in GHCi

Comment: Is it [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-posix-0.95.2) one? Why do you want to `install` it? Does it provide a binary for running or you just want to use it in your code? If it is the later case (using in code) you might want to use `cabal` or `stack` to manage dependency of the project instead of `install` it globally.

Comment: This looks like a linking issue. For example, some distributions like Arch use dynamic linking by default, without static libraries, but without additional configuration, `cabal` tries to link statically, which results in the kind of message you are seeing. For more information: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Haskell

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I am using Arch.  I was able to get it to work by uncommenting ```ibrary-vanilla: False
shared: True
executable-dynamic: True``` in my config, but am am now having similar issues with a different library ```Graphics/HGL/Internals/Events.hs:23:68: error:
    Module ‘Control.Concurrent.Chan’ does not export ‘isEmptyChan’``` ... any suggestions how to resolve these linking errors ?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia You should make that an answer!

Comment: @WarrickMacmillan That second one sounds significantly different. Worth a fresh question with  full details.

Comment: base-4.11 removed `isEmptyChan` so you need to fix the version bounds of the hgl package to account for that.

Comment: and more importantly, use an older version of GHC. You could also try to update hgl to a modern version but that may be a less trivial task.

Answer (score 1):

This is a linking issue. For example, some distributions like Arch use dynamic linking by default, without static libraries, but without additional configuration, cabal tries to link statically, which results in the kind of message you are seeing. For more information: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Haskell